# Verb + But + verb vs verb + but + noun sentence structures

Tags: grammar

Can someone please tell me the meaning of the word "but" in the following sentences:

"The figure is but the faintest, most spectral of them all"

Is it functioning as "only" or "almost"
I know from the idiom "all but + verb/adv" that but may function to mean almost
and I know in some cases but can function to mean "only":

"this central head does but consummate the sentiment of the whole company..."

Please let me know your thoughts. Thanks.

Comment: For both of those examples, insert *nothing* before each *but* and it should make sense.

Comment: In your example, the adverb "but" is a 'focusing modifier' of the noun phrase _the faintest, most spectral of them all_

Answer (score 1):

In your example sentence 'but' means 'only'.

In the phrase 'all but', the word 'but' does not mean 'almost'. It means 'except' - (definition 2 of [this dictionary entry](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/but?s=t)). The phrase 'all but' means 'everything except'